# Mais de um verbo entre conceitos - Diagrama de Conceitos UML

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software, uml, diagrama-de-classes

Como representar a situação em que um caso de uso apresenta mais de um verbo entre conceitos? Por exemplo:

- O usuário acessa o sistema e pode ver as postagens de outros usuários e também pode criar uma nova postagem.

No caso os conceitos seriam: Usuário e Postagem; e os verbos seriam: Ver e criar.

Como representar isso no diagrama de conceitos UML?

Comment: _"Um caso de uso representa uma unidade discreta da interação entre um ator (humano, dispositivo ou outro software) e o sistema. Um caso de uso é uma unidade de um trabalho significante. Por exemplo: o "login para o sistema", "registrar no sistema" e "criar pedidos" são todos casos de uso."_  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_caso_de_uso. Então, ver postagens e criar postagem são casos de uso distintos.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Desculpa a minha dúvida mas só tenho trabalhado com os nomes em inglês e não conheço bem a terminologia em português: "diagrama de conceitos" corresponde ao "use case diagram"?

Se for esse o caso, tens de ter em conta que cada *uso* corresponde a *um e um só verbo*.

Isto permite-te que separar cada *uso* em módulos de código *separados e independentes*, com inúmeras vantagens para a análise (e desenvolvimento, se for esse o caso).

No exemplo apresentado tens três casos (adicionei o requisito em que o acesso é *requerido* para a leitura e criação): [exemplo no PlantUML](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/JOrDZi8m38NtEONLsKmNdGEqqgXNCOc58YKD-0Tn7RPSenS3YnRmwjFJv_TcKMIrMW96RGmcjjuuDq012y648We1HX913xiD6qWMfOhTMxgiT_1po_dKHF58zMD4phW9Zbz6C1Y6V_XzjVS0FoKlD3AboU7lq4gQbAxg4S08J6SZpgdjdy_5VcSlxyDCIx9Q7W00)

```
@startuml
    actor usuário as u

    usecase acessa as "acessa o sistema"
    usecase vê     as "vê postagem"
    usecase cria   as "cria postagem"

    u --> (acessa)  #line:red;line.bold;text:red  : requerido
    u --> (vê)
    u --> (cria)
@enduml
```

[image: caso de uso]

Comment: Diagrama de conceitos no meu entendimento mostra somente as classes e associações, formando o modelo conceitual do domínio, que depois evolui para diagrama de classes.

Comment: Estaremos a falar deste tipo de análise (USP) https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/3720765/course/section/857605/Aula04_ModeloConceitual.pdf e https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-modelagem-conceitual/10793 ?

Se assim for, estaremos a falar de outros tipo de diagramas UML.

Comment: Entendo que o AP quis mapear um caso de uso "com mais de um verbo" para o modelo conceitual, por isso citou diagrama de conceitos. Mas caberia ter falado do diagrama de casos de uso, que é esse que você mostrou, com as setas. Confesso que não conhecia esse termo "diagrama de conceitos", não lembro de ser citado no Larman.

Comment: Segundo percebi (mas não conhecia este tipo de diagrama) das informações da USP acima, é um diagrama de classes simplificado.

Compreendo a ideia mas não sei se traz mais informações que o diagrama de classes normal.

Mesmo nesse caso, cada verbo (acção) distinto representa uma associação entre objectos (sujeitos).

Uma representação alternativa criaria dois actores "usuário" e "sistema de postagens", com três casos de uso : "acesso", "vê" e "cria".

Não sei estas ideias ajudam de algum modo?